# Incorrect sorting date / time with jquery tablesorter

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, tablesorter

i'm using plugin Tablesorter. I can not properly configure sort one of the columns.
It looks like this (days hours minutes):

```
0d04h11m
4d22h26m
27d20h14m
0d09h50m
2d02h34m
1d11h02m
```

I tried to apply {sorter:'digits'}

After sorting:

```
4d22h26m
2d02h34m
27d20h14m
1d11h02m
0d09h50m
0d04h11m
```

That is not true sorts, if the two-digit days.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: use double digit standard like _0d04h11m_ bexause that is sorting the table according to alphabets i.e. ASCII value.

Comment: If you are using my fork of tablesorter, there is a [duration parser](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/js/parsers/parser-duration.js) included with the files - [demo](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers-duration.html) - it was designed to work even if the entry only has something like `20m`.

Comment: I just have updated my code (I had to change the simbol '>' by '-'), because it has a little issue on Safari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ## UPDATED

You can use this funcition to sort your dates:

```js
$(function() {
  var sortDates = (function(){
    function dateToNumber(date){
      return parseInt(
        date.match(/\d+/g)
          .map(function(field){
            return field.length === 1 ? '0' + field : field;
          }).join('')
      , 10);
    }
    return function(date1, date2){
      return dateToNumber(date1) - dateToNumber(date2);
    };
  }());

  $("#table").tablesorter({
    textSorter : {
      1 : sortDates
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.tablesorter/2.25.1/js/jquery.tablesorter.min.js"></script>

<table id="table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>dates</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tr>
    <td>0d04h11m</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>4d22h26m</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>27d20h14m</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>0d09h50m</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>2d02h34m</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1d11h02m</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add your own parser:

**Disclaimer**: the following will only work if your data has the same forma always. Otherwise, if you can have such things as `4d`, `4d1h`, you'll need to figure out another way.

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({
    id: 'custom_sort_function',
    is: function(s) {
        return false;
    },
    format: function(s) {
        return parseInt(s.replace(/\D/g, ''), 10); // '0d04h11m' --> '00411' --> 411
    },
    type: 'numeric'
});
```

Then you add:

```
{sorter:'custom_sort_function'}
```

For further functionalities, [see the docs](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-parsers.html).

---

### Edit:

This function will give you a safer parser:

```
format: function(s) {
    var regexParser = /(?:([0-9]{1,2})d)?(?:([0-9]{1,2})h)?(?:([0-9]{1,2})m)?(?:([0-9]{1,2})s)?/;
    var matches = regexParser.exec(s);
    var days = parseInt(matches[1], 10) || 0;
    var hours = parseInt(matches[2], 10) || 0;
    var minutes = parseInt(matches[3], 10) || 0;
    var seconds = parseInt(matches[4], 10) || 0;

    return  ((days * 24 + hours) * 60 + minutes) * 60 + seconds;
}
```

And if you add this:

```
is: function(s) {
    return /^(?:([0-9]{1,2})d)?(?:([0-9]{1,2})h)?(?:([0-9]{1,2})m)?(?:([0-9]{1,2})s)?$/.test(s);
}
```

you'll have an automatic parser, so you won't need the `{sorter: 'custom_sort_function'}`.

Comment: I like your approach. Voted up! :). I hope you like mine too